# Fractional part of a Division Assembly MSP430

Tags: assembly, msp430

I've been trying to complete an assembly routine for division. This routine will allow only integer numbers as input. The problem I have is that the division in some operations will have an integer part and a fractional part. For example if I divide 10/3 = 3.333. How can I get the fractional part from that division?

Comment: Depends on how many digits you want and what format. Simplest of course is to scale by 1000 and so do 10000/3=3333 then place the decimal point as appropriate.

Comment: I am sorry for not specifying the format. Should be 3 decimal digital for the fractional part.

Answer (score 1):

If your division function gives you a remainder, multiply the remainder by 10 and repeat the division with the result, that's the first fractional number. And so on.

Multiplying by 10 is easy: Add the number with itself (add number,number) and store the result. Add it two times by itself and add the stored result. This equates to `(x*2)+(x*8) = (x*10)`.